# how to get the sudo apt-get install r-base failure

Tags: package-management

after entering the command

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

it prompts me to insert a disc labeled ubuntu 14.04.2 trusty tahr. What does that mean? Do i have to insert a disc as the prompt asks? thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You are prompted for CD since the installation CD is still listed in the sources.list as a reposioty for your system.

#### Details

Usually officia package sources are listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

and third-party repositories `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files.

If you installed from CD-ROM, there'll be a line with

```
deb cdrom:[some name]/ stable main
```

To remove it:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove it or comment it out (by adding a # at the beginning of the line)

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

---

To do it GUI Either go to ubuntu software center then to menu -> edit -> sofwtare source or run the command:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

It brings you to this, uncheck the `CD repository`

[image]